# Google Assistant make GET request and reply with server response

Tags: actions-on-google

I'd like to create an action in Google Assistant such that when a voice command is issued, the Assistant will make a GET request to a URL, like http://example.com/response.txt and just read out the plaintext response. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to [create an Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart) using Actions Builder or Dialogflow.

This Action would start with a 'Default Welcome Intent' that you should connect it to a webhook:

[image]

This webhook can be written simply using a language like Node.js

```
import {conversation} from '@assistant/conversation'

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const app = conversation()
const URL = 'http://example.com/response.txt'

app.handle('Default Welcome Intent', async conv => {
  const apiResponse = await fetch(URL)
  const text = await apiResponse.text()
  conv.add(text)
})
```

Depending on whether you just want static information or not, you may want to then add a transition to 'end conversation' to close it out.

[image]

Comment: Do I write the webhook as a Cloud Function?

Comment: You can use a Cloud Function or any other server

Comment: Google completly sunsets the Dialogflow service for no reason. This (good) answer will not work anymore and I am not aware of any alternatives to archive the same as described.